# Как найти и скопировать последнюю папку по алфавиту?

Tags: cmd, bat

```
С:\Folder1\
D:\Folder2\1.7.2_0\
D:\Folder2\2.7.2_0\
D:\Folder2\2.9.4_0\
```

В папку `D:\Folder2\` добавляются папки.
Как найти и скопировать последнюю папку по алфавиту `D:\Folder2\2.9.4_0\` в `С:\Folder1\`

```
xcopy (найти) "D:\Folder2\2.9.4_0\" "С:\Folder1\"  /S /E /Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

последний по времени создания?

```
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%F in ('
  DIR /AD /O-D /B  
') Do @(
  set myfolder=%%F
  goto exitloop
)
:exitloop
echo last folder: %myfolder%
```

Comment: Ему по алфавиту. Так что `/O-N`.

Comment: Akina Оба варианта и по алфавиту и по времени

Comment: А куда адрес папки подставлять?

Comment: А куда адрес папки подставлять?
Пишу `set myfolder = D:\Folder2` и в результате получаю последнюю папку около которой запущен bat а не которая указана

Comment: готово cd D:\Folder2

Comment: переходить не обязательно можно в вызове узазать. DIR /AD /O-D /B "D:\folder2"